# How can I explain poor grades on courses taken after obtaining my undergraduate degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, grades

I have a 3.8 undergraduate GPA with almost entirely A's in all courses. After obtaining my undergraduate degree, I took courses for fun in various subjects at two remote graduate schools. Because I was working full-time, I was exhausted a lot of the time and didn't focus on the grades. I got mostly B's, although I withdrew from a course or two when I couldn't handle both work and the courseload at the same time. I didn't get a degree but really enjoyed learning new things.

Now I'm applying to graduate school and have a real problem. I'm applying to top programs and applications want me to submit transcripts from *all* programs attended, but my grades on these "freelance" graduate courses are quite poor. How can I explain that I took them for fun and knowledge, and didn't focus much on my grades, but I'm very capable of getting good grades if I want to?

Comment: Were you in a degree program or just taking individual classes?

Comment: Technically in an MA program, but strayed widely out of it.

Comment: Are you applying to doctoral programs? Will you still be working? What has changed that suggests a different outcome?

Comment: I'm applying to MA programs, and no, I will not be working.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, there is a section on an application to explain "special circumstances" or otherwise make comments about your academic history. It would be perfectly legitimate to mention that you took these courses a) outside of a regular degree program, b) when working full-time, and c) "just for fun". And for these reasons, the grades you received do not necessarily reflect your potential in a future graduate program.

In fact, it may even be a net positive if you can spin it as evidence that you were being proactive: it was a low-stakes way to get exposure to advanced material and test whether graduate school would be of interest to you.

Full disclosure: I have never served on an admissions committee

Answer (score 2):

> How can I explain that I took them for fun and knowledge, and didn't focus much on my grades, but I'm very capable of getting good grades if I want to?

There are no magic words for this --- just be forthright and honest about your circumstances.  Roughly speaking, you explain this by saying those words you just said to us.  Applications for graduate programs always give you a chance to give a cover-letter or give additional information on your application, so find an appropriate spot for this and just tell them what you told us.